# How to get the same UV islands to occupy the same place on the texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I've created a simple box:
[image: Screenshot]

As you can see it has many similar islands that are supposed to use same place on my texture. But when I try to align similar UV islands to same positions (as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> -> Selection to 3D Cursor) Blender removes all regions but one and as result I can see just a gray color on my object at their respective places.

How to fix that behavior? I need all similar UV islands to use the same space on the texture.

Comment: I am sure that using the key-combination Shift+S is not the right way, as it pretty much places all vertices of the UV island on the position of the 3D-cursor (the UV islands thus are shrunk to 1 pixel looking as you mentioned).

Comment: @Xylvier, I didn't know it, thank you for explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no **vanilla** functionality that allows to pack all UV islands on the same place, essentially stacking them on each other.

There is an addon that comes with Blender though that can help a bit.
The name is **Magic UV**, and it comes with it's own **Pack UV** function:
[image]

The needed preparation is not too complicated if you do not have to many of those same islands:

1. First of all, you will have to make sure they are all **averaged** out:
   [image: Average Islands Scale]
   (*this will ensure that the islands are all having the same size in the UV editor, if they are the same size on the object.*)
2. Now you adjust the snapping option to vertices
   [image]
3. Now you have to go through all same islands.(single face or group of faces can be an island, what matters is the island is the same as the one you want to stack on top)
4. Select an Island and while moving it, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap on a vertex that makes the islands stack exactly on top of the other. Repeat until all same islands are stacked up.
5. Select all UV islands with <kbd>A</kbd>
6. Then finally go in the **UV menu** and use the above mentioned **UV Manipulation->Pack UV** function. Adjust the parameters to better suit your needs.

Here a visual demonstration:
[image]

Happy Blending

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer!

Comment: @Шах Hello :). If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (the green checkmark).  Thanks.